# Drupal 8 how to use different themes on subsites

Tags: drupal, theming

I have been requested to architect and develop a "site collection" where there are different sub-sites below the main umbrella site. Let's call the umbrella www.umbrella-site.net.
The subsites should be of form www.umbrella-site.net/sitex etc.

Now the subsites should use different themes from a finite set of themes. The theme should be selectable by the end user without changes in the code. The themes themselves shall be pre-programmed (as they should be approved by the PR). And the theme should be used by whole /sitex tree (based by the url)

I am not asking the full solution but a few pointers. The problems I see are:

- how to use a different theme in the subtree of urls
- how to point a theme for a subsite without changes in the code
- how to get the information of selected theme in the pages below the subsite

I would rather not to use javascript based solutions to achieve this functonality.

Of course there might be other problems when really implementing this, but I would be more than thankful if I could get any insight for the questions above.

wbr

hank

Answer (score 0):

There is a module "Theme key"

https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey

..but there's no stable version of it. Unfortunately, that's the situation for many D8 modules.

Comment: Consider also doing it programmatically: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201530/how-can-i-change-the-active-theme-programmatically